# How to update to latest version of SVN server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn, package-management, apt-get

I currently have SVN server installed on my Linux Ubuntu machine, version 1.6.12.

I see that the latest version is 1.8.x and would like to update my installation to it, so I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install subversion
svnserve --version
```

And it's telling me that it's still running version 1.6.12...

What's going on here?!? How do I actually update my installation through `apt-get`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get` searches for the updates in the repositories created for your version of Ubuntu. The SVN server version is not likely going to change until you upgrade the whole system.

Comment: Thanks @choroba (+1) - so you mean running `sudo apt-get install *` instead of `sudo apt-get install subversion`, or do you mean something else? Thanks again!

Comment: No, to upgrade your distribution, you should use `apt-get dist-upgrade`. It involves changing sources of all the repositories, takes a lot of time and can break things. Be careful, make yourself sure you really want it.

Comment: Ahhh gotchya, well... I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu (12.04) - so I don't think the distro version is the issue. It should have the latest version of SVN in it...

Comment: According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/devel/subversion, 12.04 should use subversion 1.6.17. Are you calling the right `svnserve` in `/usr/bin`?